# More efficient saveRDS(object = rbind(readRDS(fin_out), dat), file = fin_out)?

Tags: r, data.table

In R, is there a more efficient way to import an RDS of a data frame, append an existing data frame, and then write it to the same RDS than

```
saveRDS(object = rbind(readRDS(fin_out), dat), file = fin_out)
```

where `fin_out` is a string of the RDS file name and `dat` is the data frame to append?

This code works, but consumes vast RAM and is slow.

Comment: Are you tied to the RDS format? If so, I doubt there's a more efficient way. Otherwise you could try more modern table serialisation formats such as Apache Feather or Parquet.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Apache Feather or Parquet but willing to try. I used RDS rather than a CSV to save hard drive space.

Comment: CSV is going to save very little space ... `arrow::write_parquet` can be great in that the file size is small/efficient, the column `class` and other attributes are preserved natively, and you can do "lazy filtering", as in only reading the rows and columns needed (using `dplyr` lazy filtering following by `%>% collect()`). However ... it is write-once only, which means in order to add data to it, you must read all of the previous parquet file, `rbind`/combine, then re-write. (This is no different than `.rds`, but parquet does not solve that problem.)

Comment: If you need an easily-appendable solution, then I suggest using an on-disk database format might be useful, see `RSQLite` and `duckdb` packages. A benefit of these and the parquet format is the cross-platform compatibility (not shared by `.rds`).

Comment: I'm surprise that no one mentions the excellent `fst` and `qs` package.

Comment: @r2evans To be clear, I didn't mean that Arrow or Parquet allowed appending, just that they are potentially vastly more efficient than RDS, simply because RDS is very *inefficient*. But the other packages mentioned by Hieu are more efficient.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, no suggestion that you were going in a wrong direction. I was trying to expand on your suggestion by highlighting a couple of pros and cons. I'm using parquet in a datamart and while much of it is to be lauded, the immutability of it can be frustrating at times.

Answer (score 0):

## `fst` package:

```
fin_out <- tempfile()
data("airquality")

# Create a sample fin_out
fst::write_fst(transform(airquality, Temp = 0), fin_out)

# Append airquality with fin_out and write back to fin_out
fst::write_fst(rbind(airquality, fst::read_fst(fin_out)), fin_out)
```

`fst` only works with `data.frame` and `data.table` and support random column access/continuous rows access.  Furthermore, it can be a drop-in replacement for your current approach of using `readRDS`/`saveRDS`.

`qs` is a similar package to `fst`. In exchange for not able to do random read, it can save all R objects to disks.